# NameError using whenever gem in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am using whenever and seed_dump gem. I am getting the following error while running `whenever --update-crontab`.

```
config/schedule.rb:11:in `block in initialize': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::RAILS_ROOT (NameError)
```

my schedule.rb file.

```
every 48.hours do
  command "rm #{RAILS_ROOT}/db/seeds.rb"
  rake "db:seed:dump"
end
```

What does the error says? What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem `whenever` does not require or depend on Rails, thus there is no such constant.

Add the following to the top of the `schedule.rb` to fix the issue:

```
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/')
```